# SQL query with two different SQL istances

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how to make a select query in vb.net, with joins between tables contained in databases of two different instances of sql server.

thanks.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). The question is too broad to be on topic here though.

Comment: The point is not related VB.Net. You have to create what is called a "linked server" in one of your instance to let it access to another one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql linked server join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137592/sql-linked-server-join-query)